# Linux redirect output ro earlier agument

Tags: linux, sorting, io

Is there a way to redirect output on Linux to a former argument. For example,

`sort file.txt > file.txt`

Would there be a way to avoid typing file.txt again?

Comment: The command you show wouldn't work anyway; it would simply truncate `file.txt`. Note that the shell handles the redirection, so `file.txt` is opened for writing (and truncated) before `sort` is ever invoked.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate (which should be on superuser anyway): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146435

Comment: I like that this truncates the file though. Seems like a quicker way to dump file contents than `cat /dev/null > file.txt` or at least an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some commands, there may be some sort of option to avoid this kind of redundancy. But it is not the case generically for all commands in Linux.
In your case, the correct way to write what you already have is

```
sort file.txt -o file.txt
```

This will sort `file.txt` and write the results back to the same file.

If you want to save the argument so you don't have to keep typing a long file name, you could store it in a bash variable:

```
i="file.txt"; sort $i -o $i
```